# How to write a question so that it's not asking for resource recommendation?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I'd like to get some information about BIOS interrupts to write a supplementary real-mode C library: [Is there a way to get the list of all BIOS interrupts present on the current system programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555349/list-of-all-bios-interrupts)

However, my question has been flagged multiple times as it seems like I'm asking for resource recommendations.

How should I write my question so as not to have it seem like I'm asking for resource recommendations?

Comment: All the close votes are for the same reason. Not "primarily opinion-based" but resource recommendation. We don't do that sort of thing here.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to reformulate this question so that it is on topic. Understand that some questions just shouldn't be asked here, and in this situation, your best bet may be to look elsewhere.

Comment: But I looked elsewhere. That question shows that I did a search (actually, several) and couldn't come up with any useful, reliable information.

Comment: Which is still not a reason to ask it here; resource recommendations are just plain off-topic.  You have a close reason, with why it doesn't work, and what to do to get it reopened.  Reading that will help you greatly.

Comment: This question is now open again. Although an answer below appeared to recommend gaming the system in order to get the question open on a technicality, I am now of the view that the question author really would like a programmatic call. I think that's on-topic.

Answer (score 19):

At the core of the question, you *are* asking for a resource recommendation.

You want all BIOS interrupts ever done by a BIOS supplier.  I'm unaware of any actual formal BIOS standard, and there is a non-trivial number of BIOS suppliers in existence, so...you're really looking for a list of stuff.

In effect, there's no way to rewrite this question to make it seem like you're *not* asking for a list of stuff.

Answer (score -26):

Ask for, how to get the list programmatically. It is not exactly the same what you want to ask, but it is very close and it is clearly ontopic.

Clearly mention in the question, that "it is impossible" is also an acceptable answer. Answerers have a habit to not give negative answers, even if they are perfectly okay, instead they vote the question to close.

Another trick is to delete your closed question, and ask a little bit later in ontopic form. Note, re-posting a closed/deleted question is clearly a misuse, never do that! But you can re-ask a similar question, which is already ontopic.

Note, questions tend to remain closed on the main site, even if their offtopic reason was long solved. It is because the community simply dislikes to reopen posts on unclear reasons.

If your efforts won't lead to solution (reopen), initiate a thread about it on the meta site. It will result a lot of negative votes and likely a closed/deleted meta question, but you have a high chance to collect at least 5 community members to take care your main site post. At least, if your question is really reopenable.

The important thing is what on the main site happens. One of the real functions of the meta site is to distract the fights from the main.

And collect 3000 ASAP to make this site a little bit better.

Comment: A conversation from underneath this answer has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211913/discussion-on-answer-by-peterh-reinstate-monica-how-to-write-a-question-so-tha).