# How do I write good, well received questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been scrolling through Stack Overflow, and I've noticed that none of the recent questions have more than 1 upvote, and many, many more have downvotes. I've read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and followed its guidelines as best I can, however, it doesn't seem to help.

How do I write a good, well received question? Should I move to another website and ask there? Or should I wait for my question to age and hope that its popularity goes up?

Comment: How long did you take to *prepare* your last questions? ([ask] is about a reasonable minimum, not necessarily "good" questions.)

Comment: Read the links at the bottom of that help center article.  In particular, [this one](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), written by the top rep earner on Stack Overflow, and [this one](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without reposting the complete help-center article you are linking yourself. Maybe it is better to narrow your question a bit.

Comment: Well reading a brunch (20+) of your question selected randomly, hidding their in both original and current form. I must say that they look good from my "0 knowledge" C perspective. I do not know what it takes to meet `[c]` standard, but you look on your way. The fact that you are asking "How to get better" is refreshing from the daily rant.

Comment: Good question. It's specifically about C questions though (although C++ questions will follow a similar path), so maybe mention that in the title.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just about writing "good, well received questions". I was just using C as an example.

Comment: "however, it doesn't seem to help". You seem to be referencing a specific question or questions. It would help to narrow this quite broad question if you included a question text here of yours that didn't fare well (or at least, a link to such a question). Just speaking generically, this is too broad to be answered effectively.

Answer (score 17):

The reception a question gets on Stack Overflow also depends on the tags that apply to that question. Each (or most, anyway) tag has a community of users that follow that tag rather closely. Some tag communities are "looser" about what constitutes a good question, some are "tighter".

I've noticed that many of the users that follow the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag will generally regard a question that can be answered by consulting the reference documentation as a bad question, reflecting no effort on the part of the OP. Also tending to be heavily down-voted are questions that show that the OP has a complete misconception about the very basics of the language.

So, as far as

> How do I write a good, well received question?

is concerned, I would recommend (for the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, anyway) that you make sure it's not covered in readily-available reference sources first.

Comment: i don't follow the `c` tag, but i disagree with these users. if the question has a clear answer from the documentation then it should be answered with quoted text + explanation and a link to the documentation. Lots of high voted questions are like this and it's often easier to find answers on SO than in the official docs. If the question is a duplicate of another SO question then that's different of course

Comment: @Chris_Rands that works both ways though - that rather large group of users disagrees with you. I wish you good luck arguing against a community consensus in this community-driven site ;)

Comment: @Gimby Sometimes SO is the reference for programming questions rather than the official documentation. If we discourage such questions SO is diminished as a resource IMO

Answer (score 11):

Since there's already a wealth of information on this topic (here and elsewhere), I'll just critique the questions you've asked.

[How to get the most significant bit of an unsigned 8-bit type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493979/how-to-get-the-most-significant-bit-of-an-unsigned-8-bit-type-in-c)

This question seems fine.  It got one downvote, probably from someone who thought you ought to do a bit more prior research.

[Is there a way to get the list of all BIOS interrupts present on the current system programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555349/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-list-of-all-bios-interrupts-present-on-the-current-sys)

This one has already been covered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382562/how-to-write-a-question-so-that-its-not-asking-for-resource-recommendation).  Frankly, I don't see the problem with it, other than it superficially resembles a resource recommendation.

[Why is xor'ing DS not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640036/why-is-xoring-ds-not-allowed)

So..."Why" questions.  There is a good way and a bad way to ask these.  You appear to have asked it the good way, out of *practical* (and not idle) curiosity and genuine confusion about the underlying principles.

I'm not a fan of the other kind, which are questions that attempt to solicit a discussion about why some obscure language feature or framework design choice was made (often accompanied by some rant about how it was the wrong decision), questions that are best answered *elsewhere,* by the folks who made the decision in the first place (if they're so inclined).

[Odd behavior when using "inc %si"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642620/odd-behavior-when-using-inc-si)

As you might have already guessed by the posted comments, your first revision of this question did not include a code sample that reproduces the problem you were describing.

Comment: I'm not a C developer myself, but I could have answered that question about getting the MSB from the top of my head. Maybe I wouldn't have downvoted it, but it definitely wouldn't get an upvote from me.Also_usually_ the exact question pops up when you search for the exact question title in Google, but for this one, it still shows a duplicate from 2013. Beginner questions for which answers are abundantly available tend to attract downvotes for lack of research effort.

Comment: The "duplicate from 2013" in question is asking for two bits. The answers suggested shifting to the right 6 bits, which is what I originally asked about in my question (because I got the wrong result).

Comment: I really hate it when answers to questions about improving explicitly point out major problems with the post and then claim the post is fine.

Comment: @jpmc26: I'm sorry, but I don't know to what you are referring.